# Compatible splitting of sub-exact sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

We work with vector spaces over a field. We have the following commutative diagram with exact rows:

[image]

$\iota_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the canonical inclusion and projection, and they have, respectively, a canonical retraction $\rho_1$ and a canonical section $\iota_2$. The other maps are unknown. The numbers $y_1, y_2$ and $k$ are some non-negative integers. My question is the following:

> Is it possible to split the upper sequence in a way compatible with the canonical splitting of the lower sequence, i.e., to find a retraction $\beta$ of $\alpha$ and a section $\delta$ of $\gamma$ such that
>   $$ f \circ \beta = \rho_1 \circ g \quad \text{and} \quad g \circ \delta = \iota_2 \circ h\ ?$$

Note that, if such maps $\beta$ and $\delta$ exist, they are unique, since for any retraction $g'$ of $g$ and $f'$ of $f$ the following equalities must hold:

$$ \beta = f' \circ \rho_1 \circ g \quad \text{and} \quad \delta = g' \circ \iota_2 \circ h.$$

So we can start out by choosing $f'$ and $g'$ (retractions of injective maps always exist for vector spaces), defining $\beta$ and $\delta$ as in the above formulas, and checking whether they satisfy the desired properties. Let us focus exclusively on $\beta$ (the arguments for $\delta$ are analogous). It turns out that $\beta$ is automatically a retraction of $\alpha$, since
$$ \beta \circ \alpha = f' \circ \rho_1 \circ g \circ \alpha = f' \circ \rho_1 \circ \iota_1 \circ f = {\rm id}_{V_1}.$$
So far, so good. But how do we know whether $f \circ \beta = \rho_1 \circ g$? This can be rewritten as
$$(f \circ f') \circ (\rho_1 \circ g) = (\rho_1 \circ g).$$

But how do we know whether we can find $f'$ satisfying this property? And notice that, if we do, then every retraction $f'$ of $f$ must satisfy this too, which seems a bit puzzling.

**Edit:** I figured out some explicit examples where this works and where it does not. So it does not always work, but it is not clear to me whether there is a nice sufficient condition for this compatible splitting to exist.

Comment: A straightforward way to answer this is that this happens if and only if $g(V)=(g(V)\cap V_1^k) \oplus (g(V)\cap V_2^k)$, i.e. $g(V)$ has a basis that can be split in two parts, the first one can be completed to a basis of $V_1^k$ and the second one into a basis of $V_2^k$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @PavelČoupek The condition you mention should be equivalent to $\gamma$ having a section $\delta$ such that $g \circ \delta = \iota_2 \circ h$, right? Which should imply the existence of the desired $\beta$ as well and hence is precisely what I would like to have. So while it helps clarify the situation, it is really just a restatement of the problem in different words, I think. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I agree, this seems like a restatement, so I wonder what form of answer do you expect: For example, if the important pieces you consider are the maps $f, h$ with their domains and codomains, I think that this always happens no matter what $V$ and $g$ is when you assume that $Ext^1$ of $f, g$ viewed as representations of the quiver $\bullet \rightarrow \bullet$ vanishes. Another possible answer, and further reformulation of the comment above, is that this happens if and only if the maps $f, g, h$ admit compatible splittings, i.e. if the upper ses is a direct summand in the lower. And so on.

Comment: (Also let me point out that the Ext-criterion mentioned above is rather useless since in the situation at hand, vanishing of such ext would probably mean that one of $V_1^{y_1}, V_2^{y_2}$ would need to be $0$; it is just to demonstrate that you can answer the question in various ways, and if reformulation is not what you are looking for, it is not clear (to me) what is.)

Comment: Neither it is to me, I guess :D but thanks for the reformulations!